# How can I properly cite Cicero's Lorem Ipsum text?

Tags: citing, lipsum

I want to properly cite the "lorem ipsum" text I use (e.g. with package `lipsum`) in my bibliography. But - where exactly was it "published" (as opposed to spoken out)? Or - should I cite the actual speech? Does it have a date?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have to do anything with TeX, as it is about how to cite an [(intentionally nonsensical) Latin text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum The text is a scrambled version of Cicero’s [*De finibus bonorum et malorum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_finibus_bonorum_et_malorum)

Comment: Most of the words are not Latin, so it is not even a Latin text. (But then so is much of the stuff that people pass off as Latin nowadays - what with "mediae" and "datas").

Answer (score 3):

If you are generating the text with `lipsum`, why not consider citing it?

```
@Manual{lipsum,
    title = {lipsum -- Easy access to the Lorem Ipsum dummy text},
    author = {Patrick Happel},
    year = {2014},
    note = {\LaTeX~package version 1.3},
    url = {https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum},
}
```

Comment: Somehow I feel citing Cicero is the more appropriate thing to do, but it's a fair suggestion I suppose.